# How to enable the :screenshot command from Firefox Web Console

Tags: firefox, screenshot

[Firefox’s :screenshot command](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2018/08/24/firefoxs-screenshot-command-2018/) claims that you can do this:

> Once you’re in the Web Console, you can type `:sc` and then hit
>   <kbd>Tab</kbd> to `autocomplete :screenshot`.

On my version of Firefox, 61.0.1, running on Ubuntu 18.04, It shows this when I attempt it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shiftt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> I see:

> [image]

I do see the icon in the upper right corner, so then why isn't the command working? Did they remove it?

> [image]

Comment: From your link: "but the coders at Mozilla have brought command-line screenshotting back with :screenshot, **currently available in Firefox Nightly and Firefox Dev Edition**."

Comment: ahh.  So I wonder why they excluded it from normal releases.

Comment: The way to look at it is that you'll get it back in the normal release in a few months :)

Comment: Ok that sounds good to me!